# Network Solutions hosting URL looks weird for Apache server

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, hosting

I was trying to prettify URLs for dynamically generated pages on my website, so that when a user visited the virtual URL `topicview/interesting-user-friendly-text` he would really be seeing, under the hood, `topicview.php?topicid=123`

I added the necessary code to my .htaccess file to replace the `topicview/interesting-text` part of the URL with `topicview.php?topicname=interesting-test`, but the Regex kept misfiring.

So, I changed the Regex to return the entire URL so I could see why it wasn't working with this code:

```
#Allow for topicview/topic-name URLs
RewriteRule (.+)$ topicview.php?topicname=$1 [L]
```

I then visited `topicview/user-friendly-text`. I'm not sure if this is unique to Network Solutions hosting, however, when I examined the `topicname` GET paramter, I got this string in return:

`data/1/2/323/232/823238/user/999999/htdocs/topicview.php`

This URL was not displayed in the `topicname` GET parameter, just a regular file, like `index.php` or `topicview.php`, if I just visit the URL `index.php` or `topicview.php`

Why is the URL internally represented like this to the Apache server, and how can I rewrite my `mod_rewrite` code to get a more user friendly virtual URL for the `topicview.php?topicid=1` pages?

thanks

Comment: what shows when you access topicview with a string parameter and you put var_dump($_GET);

Comment: like "topicview.php?topicid=4" - is that what you mean by string parameter?

Comment: Can you create a file called `info.php` with this code `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` and then open `http://domain.com/info.php` to check what is its `DOCUMENT_ROOT` value.

Comment: Yes, the `data/1/2/323/232/823238/user/999999/htdocs` is the Document_Root value reported by phpinfo(). Is there a way I can get the Pattern part of the RewriteRule to just look at the Request_URI, which is a much simpler `topicview.php` ?

Answer (score 0):

For the friendly URL try this in your .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^/?topicview/([^/.*]+)/?$ topicview.php?topicname=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but this doesn't address the main problem, that the Regex `^/?topicview/([^/.*]+)/?$` will not match anything, since the URL that Apache is looking at is `data/1/2/323/232/823238/user/999999/htdocs/topicview.php` for some reason, instead of just `topicview/some-text`

Comment: What you've described is messed up.  Not sure what version of Apache you're using, but in my experience the first section of a RewriteRule always looks at the REQUEST_URI,

Answer (score 0):

The pattern matched in a RewriteRule is normally the similar to the REQUEST_URI but the behaviour you describe suggests it is matching against the REQUEST_FILENAME or something similar which is the file path including the full document root.

This would suggest your RewriteRule is not in your .htaccess file but instead in your  or  rules in the Apache config files, correct?

Instead you should try getting the value you want using a RewriteCond so you can guarantee you are matching against the REQUEST_URI, for example:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)$
RewriteRule . topicview.php?topicname=%1 [L]
```

Note the %1 rather than $1 which allows you to use values captured in the RewriteCond.