# mod_rewrite RewriteRule with REQUEST_URI

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite

How can I specify the mod_rewrite RewriteRule to use the REQUEST_URI as the pattern it checks, rather than the full directory path of the file?

Currently, I'm able to pass the URI through a GET param, like so:

`(.+) topicview.php?topicname=%{REQUEST_URI}`

But I want the `(.+)` Pattern to match the REQUEST_URI itself, rather than the directory path, which is ugly and looks like `data/2/2/3233/user/21212/morestuff/more/topicview.php`

Comment: What is the URL you are sending to web server and what is your rewrite rule?

Comment: the URL that the user enters is "domain.com/topicview/user-friendly-text-here"

Comment: However, my server for some reason internally views that URL as "data/2/2/3233/user/21212/morestuff/more/topicview.php" - see my other question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28688075/network-solutions-hosting-url-looks-weird-for-apache-server

Comment: ok let me address it your other question.

Answer (score 0):

As per my answer to your other question at [Network Solutions hosting URL looks weird for Apache server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28688075/network-solutions-hosting-url-looks-weird-for-apache-server/28732216#28732216) try using a RewriteCond instead to capture the value you want:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)$
RewriteRule . topicview.php?topicname=%1 [L]
```

Note the %1 rather than $1 which allows you to use values captured in the RewriteCond.